# Shrink wrapping an SVG to the size of a symbol element without hard-coding dimensions

Tags: html, css, svg

Say that one has a sprite sheet as follows:

```
<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 32 32" id="square-thing" class="inner">
    <path d="..."/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 64 32" id="wide-thing" class="inner">
    <path d="..."/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 32 128" id="tall-thing" class="inner">
    <path d="..."/>
  </symbol>
  <!-- ...more things of all shapes and sizes! -->
</svg>
```

This sprite sheet is referenced in a document:

```
<svg class="outer"><use xlink:href="#thing1" /></svg>
<svg class="outer"><use xlink:href="#thing2" /></svg>
<svg class="outer"><use xlink:href="#thing3" /></svg>
```

When rendered, each of the symbols will have at least some space between the `.outer` element and `.inner` element, as seen below:

[image: SVG assets with various spacing between outer and inner elements]

The Chrome user agent seems to set a width of `300px` and a height of `150px` for the `.outer` SVG element, which causes the spacing.

A more holistic example of how this might be used:

```
<a href="#">An Icon - <svg class="outer"><use xlink:href="#thing" /></svg></a>
```

I would like the `.outer` SVG here to automatically size itself to match the font size of the `<a>` that it is inside of *without having extra spacing around the `.inner` element*.

**How might one make the `.outer` element shrink-wrap itself to the size of `.inner` with the following requirements:**

- No setting explicit width and height properties on the `.outer` element.  The referenced symbols can have wildly unpredictable viewbox dimensions.
- No javascript.

I've tried a plethora of CSS based approaches to no avail.

A working fiddle can be found here with an interactive demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/lleber/7z8Lmy9k/

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: What you need to do is to put each icon on the same grid and same size viewbox. That way the sizes will be equal and the padding will be too

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.  In my case, the viewbox sizes cannot be the same.  If the original requirements aren't feasible, then an answer of "not possible" is very acceptable.

Comment: If it can't be the same then you'll always have that issue. Can I ask why?

Comment: Sure, the sprite sheet is a product of a build process that aggregates arbitrary assets into a sprite sheet.

Comment: Take those assets and throw them into figma / sketch and export them from there again in a consistent viewbox, no? The build will still do its thing...

Comment: So instead of eliminating padding, it would simply normalize it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237339/discussion-between-luke-a-leber-and-dominik).

Comment: It would. I have had to do this numerous times and trying to add padding per svg is WAY harder than just aligning the viewboxes

Comment: After some experimentation, it may be as simple as preprocessing the viewbox of the inner <symbol> to the <svg> as it's called -- which is well within the power of a templating engine.  For example: `<svg viewBox="0 0 448 448"><use xlink:href="#thing" /></svg>` where the viewbox of `#thing` is also `0 0 448 448`.  This seems to allow the SVG to be sized implicitly based on the font size of where it's located.